# Can I stack Shapeshift druid sizes increases?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, druid, creature-size

I'm playing a druid with the alternative shapeshift ability from *PHB2*. And something keeps bringing up question marks.

All the shapeshift forms (except for first Predator and Aerial forms) keep saying: "Your size increases by one category (to a maximum of Colossal)" and at the beginning of the shapeshift ability it says: "If you are capable of taking more than one form, you can shapeshift directly between two forms without returning to your normal form."

So, if I shapeshift from human (Medium) to ferocious slayer form in round 1 to become Large, and then shapeshift from ferocious slayer form to forest avenger form in round 2, do I increase my size category from Large to Huge? And if so, does this work when I go from human → avenger → slayer?

Answer (score 7):

Each new shapeshift form replaces the previous, even if you do not stop in human form between. So when you are in forest avenger form in round 2, you are no longer in ferocious slayer form, and thus no longer benefit from its size increase.

Conclusion: all shapeshift size changes are relative to your size without shapeshift; you cannot continue to stack them on each other by shifting from one form to another.

Comment: It *should* work that way, but I'm not sure that it *does*: "...you can shapeshift directly between two forms without returning to your normal form... Unless otherwise noted in the descriptions below, you retain your size and space when you adopt a new form..."

So, you might want to call out whether you are ruling that 'you retain your size' means that you retain (or assume) your normal size when changing to predator form, regardless of what form you were using previously. Plus references or quotes would be nice.

Comment: My old comment here is kinda ignorant, but has one good point: a rules reference would be nice. Even mentioning that this is the same effect, from the same source, on the same target, but with different results (Players Handbook (2003) 172 http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#combining-magical-effects ), I really think that editing something like that in would make this a very good answer. Obviously, the querent is unlikely to be back to accept the answer, but it would still be helpful.